# Randomly getting 'Request timed out' in every 15 minutes

Tags: networking, router, internet

I am living in Germany and i am using Vodafone home internet. I got some internet interruptions for some seconds. It effects me too much when i play online games. I've called them several times and they changed router 2 times. They gave vodafone docsis 3.1 router. I am not sure if router has problem. I created some ping traces. They cant solve this problem. Maybe you can help me to find the problem. I can buy a good router but i am not sure if router is the problem.

Note: I use normally wireless but cable connection gives same result

This is the result when i ping my router : http://notes.io/9mqH

This is the result when i ping 1.1.1.1 : http://notes.io/9mqD

Comment: Can you (a) disconnect from Vodafone and then (b) connect to your smart phone (turn on phone hotspot) . See if this alternate connection solves your problem. That will help you determine if the issue is your Vodafone connection or your computer.

Comment: It is Vodafone problem for sure. It happens for all devices.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  So (a) if no router (that is, devices connected to the Vodafone modem, then bang on Vodafone some more, or (b) if you have your own router attached to the Vodafone modem, then upgrade the firmware in your router to see if that helps.

Comment: a but i am really tired of calling them. I need to try another router or i will ask for cancelling my contract

Comment: That is probably the thing to do. I had a love / hate relationship with my ISP. Out every morning for about a month and otherwise not bad. I kept records and they finally found their issue in the big (very big) connection box into our neighbourhood. All well since.

Comment: Is there any way to check signals of the cable. Before connecting it to router?

Comment: The exterior cables and signal need to be checked by the ISP. You said all devices, so not likely an interior Ethernet cable.

Comment: They checked it multiple times, they said it is ok but there is a possibility that they checked it when it was stable.

Comment: I have disabled Wifi and connected only 1 laptop via Lan. There was still interruptions. I think it is not the router.

Comment: But you said the interruptions happen on a devices. Update Firmware on any router you own. Ask the ISP to update the firmware on their modem.